# Voyager episode where they encounter a phenomenon that contains a 21st century astronaut

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

What is the name of the Voyager episode where they encounter a phenomenon that contains a 21st century astronaut?  It's an elliptical something or other.

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research. Even the most cursory search would have found you the answer.

Comment: as an example: "voyager 21st century astronaut"

Comment: Terribly sorry chaps, perhaps I should have employed a team first. When is a question permissible? So as to avoid further retribution from the knowledge police.

Comment: @Valorum.......

Comment: @Jezza - My general rule of thumb for "insufficient research" is where directly googling the question title *instantly* comes up with the right answer.

Comment: @Valorum, fair enough, however it just happened to be on my mind, when registering. As you can see, this was my first question. So, perhaps a modicum of leeway should be allowed?

Comment: @Jezza - [Rule 33](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/lurk-moar) applies when dealing with new users. You might get a little extra politeness, but you still don't get to ask dodgy questions :-)

Comment: @Valorum, haha, quite right, read the forum rules first. :-)

Comment: @Valorum. Would the question, "what is the previous, negative rating record ?", be acceptable?

Comment: @Jezza - In what context? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Valorum. Mine appears to be @ - 3. Was just wondering, how low any other new users had managed to plummet.

Comment: @jezza - [Lowest-scoring question of all time (including deleted questions)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10036/lowest-scoring-question-of-all-time-including-deleted-questions) and  [Which question on SFF has the highest number of downvotes?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/which-question-on-sff-has-the-highest-number-of-downvotes)

Comment: @Valorum... Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The episode is called "[One Small Step](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/One_Small_Step_(episode))" from Season 6 of Voyager

The anomaly encountered is called a '**graviton ellipse**'

From the wiki description:

> known for suddenly appearing out of subspace, enveloping whatever is
>   in the vicinity or whatever attracts it, then going back into
>   subspace. Chakotay stands up from his chair and recalls the Ares IV
>   and its loss to such a phenomenon. This is why it appeared to Kelly to
>   have come from nowhere

[image]

The astronaut is [John Kelly](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/John_Kelly) - apparently lost in the first manned Mars mission, but found by the Voyager crew centuries later due to the subspace anomaly

[image]